# how can I get last 7 days of data being my date field a number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get last 7 days data excluding Sunday being my date field a number. How can I do  it? Field structure 20140425. For example is I run the statement today it should give me date range between 20140424 - 20140417 excluding 20140420.

Comment: The database should have used a `date` datatype.  That would make this much easier and far more intuitive.  Especially if the range spans month or year boundaries.

Comment: Why are you using a number instead of a datetime datatype for this data?  I posted an answer that should work, but ideally you would convert this column to it's proper datatype.

Comment: this is the way the table structure has been designed by the provider and I have to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hitch is of course converting the number based date to a real date.  This seems to work:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(char(10), 20140425))
```

To expand, your query would look like this:

```
select *
  from [Table]
 where convert(datetime, convert(char(10), [columnname])) between convert(varchar, getdate() - 8, 101) and convert(varchar, getdate() - 1, 101)
   and datepart(DW, convert(datetime, convert(char(10), [columnname]))) <> 1
```

The convert(varchar, getdate - 1, 101) will return you 12:00am yesterday morning. My first pass didn't include that and would've only given a 6 day range.

Comment: Note that this requires `DATEFIRST` to be `7`, which is the default in U.S. English but can be changed.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using getdate()-1 and getdate()-8, then look for Sunday on that range and then converting date into number? I have to convert date range into a number and pass it to my field not the opposite because it will takes a lot of time to populate the data.

Comment: I just updated the query to reflect being between -8 and -1.  I also added a convert to the getdate to truncate the time off of the result of getdate()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE CAST(DateField AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
AND   CAST(DateField AS DATE) <=   GETDATE()
AND   DATEPART(DW,CAST(DateField AS DATE)) <> 1
```

Comment: Note that this requires `DATEFIRST` to be `7`, which is the default in U.S. English but can be changed.

Comment: what are you talking about DATEFIRST?